# Windows 7 rightclick menu from toolbar like ALT-SPACE?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar, context-menu, aero

The menu containing `Restore, Move, Resize, Minimize, Maximize and Close` accessible through right click on a window titlebar or click on the upper left form icon, was before the new Aero stuff available from right click on an active program in the task bar.
How can I access it now from the task bar?

I use it when a window is outside the screen, by selecting Move and then pressing an arrow, and then move the mouse cursor to where I want the window and finally clicking where I want it.

As a workaround, to retrieve a window that is outside the current screen (say that you have 2 screens and one is currently showing another pc) I'm doing the following:

1. Alt tab to the program
2. Press ALT-SPACE
3. Press m
4. Press an arrow key
5. Move the mouse into view
6. Left click the mouse

However, I think it's better to be able to see the menu rather than guessing the menu.
Is it possible to show the above mentioned menu from the task bar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RightMouseClick</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case (window on another monitor you can't see), you can just use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then press <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> till it appears on the visible monitor.